# 2016 Toyota Corolla A/C not working

Tags: toyota, ac, corolla

I just purchased a 2016 Corolla (15000 miles) in Feb 2020. Went to turn on the A/C and hot air comes out. Took it back to the dealer (which was a Nissan dealer) and they did a few tests and recommended I take it to a Toyota dealer. I believe the compressor is working and the freon is charged. Well, this is what the Nissan Service dept told me.

What else can I check out? So mad at myself for not checking the AC when I bought this car. I feel this is why the previous owner dumped the car.

Comment: Check the fine print of the sales contract, and maybe talk to a lawyer as the dealer that sold it may be responsible for fixing it.

Comment: @GdD - In the States, when purchasing a vehicle from a dealership, the dealership will give you what's called a [We Owe Slip](https://www.insigniagroup.com/blog/the-we-owe-thats-what-its-all-about). If what is wrong with the vehicle is not on this slip, the dealership has no obligation to fix it. The only other way it might get fixed at other than the owner's expense if is an extended warranty was purchased with the vehicle.

Comment: To the OP: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell us if you can hear the compressor kick on/off when the A/C is turned on? Does the air coming out feel like it's the ambient air temperature (inside the vehicle) or does it feel hotter, like its actually getting heated?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I used to work in the industry. [Here's from OK.](https://www.ok.gov/usedcarcommission/faqs.html). [Here's from Indiana](https://www.in.gov/attorneygeneral/files/Consumer_Bill_of_Rights.pdf). [Here's from NIADA.](https://www.niada.com/PDFs/Information/Accounting/SampleAcctManual.pdf) ... Need any more proof? [Here's a Google Search on the subject.](https://t.ly/B56q).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What a trove! Thanks for the correction: you're certainly right that such regulations are common, and I'll amend my comment to conform. Interestingly, even when building on your searches, I find nothing regarding a "we owe slip" (or similar) in California, either in the codes or the administrative rules. Given its prevalence in other states, I wouldn't be surprised at all if it existed here as well, but I don't see it yet.

Comment: The purchaser of a used car may have signed an "as-is" or "no-warranty" form as part of the purchase; if so, the dealer will be successful in avoiding responsibility. Here in California, no-warranty forms are commonly seen as window stickers and contrived to look like Monroneys; I expect they're included in the purchase packet.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I didn't find one for CA, either. However, considering how CA tries to protect its consumers in far greater ways than even the consumer might want, I'll bet CA has something similar maybe just named something else. The "we owe" isn't a bad thing, necessarily. The problem lies in the fact many consumers really don't know what it is or what it's for, but is put in front of them for signing when purchasing the vehicle. I'd bet the explanation is quite often glossed over by the dealership during the "deal".

Comment: @Paulster2 I agree with everything you say.

Comment: Compressor and temperature question. I had 2 people tell me the compressor is turning on. To me, the feel of the air blowing would be more ambient. What I have recently notice is the front defrost does not work as well as it should. Tried to use it on a day when it was 90degrees and raining heavily. A friend had asked his mechanic about my problem and he mentioned there could be a block somewhere is the system-sometimes the dashboard needs to be taken apart to find it and that is a huge job. I have to take my car in for a recall on it's airbags. I might talk to them about the AC issue